# Deriving solution $xM(x,y)+yN(x,y)=C$ of exact homogeneous ODE $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Trying to prove that if $M(x,y)\,dx+N(x,y)\,dy=0$ is an exact and homogeneous ODE, then $xM(x,y)+yN(x,y)=C$ is the solution of the ODE.
I know that, since it is an exact ODE then:

$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=M(x,y)$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=N(x,y)$$

$$\phi = \int M(x,y)\,dx + k_1(y)$$

$$\phi = \int N(x,y)\,dy + k_2(x)$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial y} M(x,y)\,dx+k_1'(y)$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=N(x,y)=\int \frac{\partial}{\partial x} N(x,y)\,dx+k_1'(y)$$

$$N(x,y)=N(x,y) + k_1'(x)$$

Furthermore, as it is homogeneous:

$$x^nM\left(1,\frac{y}{x}\right)\,dx+y^nN\left(\frac{x}{y},1\right) = 0$$

But I can not go far in the proof, if you can help me I would be grateful.